# Remove all .class files from folders in bash

Tags: find, rm

I'm making a bash file to remove all .class files that java generates inside the src folder and it's subfolders. The structure is:

```
project
   src
      /utils
         utils.class
      /game
         game.class
         gameManager.class
```

So when I execute the script inside the `project` folder, it search all `.class` files and remove them, but it doesn't work.

I just created this script:

```
find . -path "src/*/*" -name "*.class" -exec rm -f {} \;
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: All the files under src

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It doesn't work because the path won't start with `src`, it will start with `./src`.

Your command line can be corrected into this:

```
find . -type f -path "./src/*/*" -name "*.class" -exec rm -f {} \;
```

Alternatively,

```
find . -type f -path "./src/*/*" -name "*.class" -delete
```

If you're happy deleting all `*.class` files *anywhere* under `src` (not just in subdirectories thereof):

```
find src -type f -name "*.class" -delete
```

Comment: Has the first line the same behaviour that the second one?

Comment: @albert Yes. I just added `-type f`, because `-delete` will also remove directories whereas `rm -f` won't (on the off chance that  you have a directory whose name matches the pattern).

Comment: I'm looking for one last thing: `find` return any value? so if it found something returns 0 or if it doens't find a file it reutrns a -1 or 1?

Comment: @albert `find` exits with an exit code of 0 if no errors occurred. This is regardless of whether it found anything or not. You may add `-print` before or after the `-delete` and redirect the output to a file. Testing the size of this file afterwards will tell you whether it did anything or not. Test this with `test -s find_output.txt && echo 'Files were removed'` or something similar.

Answer (score 1):

```
cd ./project/src && \
find . -name '*.class' -exec rm -f {} \;
```

No need to complicate simple things.

Comment: I don't want to use cd, I want to do inside the `project` folder

Comment: @don_crissti Yes that's right, but I use `find .` just in case we need the case `-name .`